# 'ActionSheetIOS' is not exported from 'react-native-web/dist/index'

Tags: javascript, reactjs, react-native, expo

How to avoid the this kind of warning? 
My app is working but it gives warning in terminal like below

```
Compiled with warnings.
/home/karim/Desktop/React-Native/RN-Complete-Guide/node_modules/react-navigation-header- 
buttons/src/overflowMenuPressHandlers.js
Attempted import error: 'ActionSheetIOS' is not exported from 'react-native-web/dist/index'.
```

It is because of of I imported `HeaderButtons` and `HeaderButton` from `react-navigation-header-buttons` like below

```
import { HeaderButtons } from "react-navigation-header-buttons";
import { HeaderButton } from "react-navigation-header-buttons";
```

And I am using react-native 4.x veriosn. 
  is there any way to avoid this warning?

Answer (score 2):

[This file](https://github.com/vonovak/react-navigation-header-buttons/blob/master/src/overflowMenuPressHandlers.js) in the source for `react-navigation-header-buttons` imports `ActionSheetIOS`, which is [not supported by React Native web applications](https://github.com/necolas/react-native-web/issues/1630). This seems like it's probably an issue with React Native web itself, as even importing the `ActionSheetIOS` component in your project without *actually* using it will cause a crash from my past experience.

You probably won't be able to use `react-navigation-header-buttons` for your solution because of this issue. The authors also go on to say [in their README](https://github.com/vonovak/react-navigation-header-buttons#react-navigation-header-buttons) that web support is currently experimental:

> Supports iOS and Android, web support is experimental.

I'd suggesting either finding a way to avoid this library or flag an issue on the repo to suggest swapping `ActionSheetIOS` in with a cross-platform action sheet solution like [`react-native-action-sheet`](https://github.com/expo/react-native-action-sheet).

Comment: I never used ActionSheetIOS but it gives warning

Comment: It looks like the source code for the react-navigation-header-buttons imports ActionSheetIOS. You may need to find an alternative solution such as manual styling for your header buttons. Will edit answer

Answer (score 1):

in react-native-web/dist/index.js i exported
export { ActionSheetIOS }; and somehow the warning disappeared

Comment: I would not recommend changing anything in your node_modules folder. This folder should not be considered part of your source code.